# Crop Image into CGRect always starts from x:0 and y:0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, crop

I have this snippet code, which works fine on my side, it crops an image based on the size of my draggable UIImageView (which is called `cropOverlay`):

```
func cropImage() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: cropOverlay.frame.origin.x, y: cropOverlay.frame.origin.y, width: cropOverlay.frame.size.width, height: cropOverlay.frame.size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 0.0)
        originalImgView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        imageToEdit = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        originalImgView.image = imageToEdit
        resizeImageViewToImageSize(originalImgView)
        cropOverlay.frame = originalImgView.frame

        print("cropOverlay: \(cropOverlay.frame)")
        print("originalImgView: \(originalImgView.frame)")
        print("imageToEdit: \(imageToEdit.size.width) - \(imageToEdit.size.height)\n")
    }
```

here's what I get in the XCode console:

```
cropOverlay: (139.25111636459152, 154.66666666666663, 135.49776727081695, 426.66666666666674)
originalImgView: (139.25111636459152, 154.66666666666663, 135.49776727081695, 426.66666666666674)
imageToEdit: 134.33333333333334 - 423.0
```

So, my console log shows the right X and Y positions of my `cropOverlay` imageView, as well as my `originalImageView` frame data. But the issue is that it doesn't matter where I move my `cropOverlay` imageView to, even if the console says it's at X: 139 and Y: 154, the image I get as result starts from X.0 and Y:0. Check these screenshots for better understanding my issue:

**BEFORE**
[image: BEFORE...]

**AFTER APPLYING THE cropImage() func**
[image: AFTER]

PS: my `resizeImageViewToImageSize(originalImgView)` function simply resizes my `originalImageView`'s frame accordingly to its UIImage size and centers it on the screen.
As you can see, the cropped image size is right, but it started from the X and Y = 0 of my originla image.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
As suggested below, I've edited my cropImage() function like this:

```
func cropImage() {

        let cutImageRef: CGImage = (originalImgView.image!.cgImage?.cropping(to: cropOverlay.frame))!
        imageToEdit = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)

        originalImgView.image = imageToEdit
        resizeImageViewToImageSize(originalImgView)
        cropOverlay.frame = originalImgView.frame
```

}

But this is the result I get:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apple method for CGImage

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping

> cropping(to:)
>
> Creates a bitmap image using the data contained within a subregion of
>   an existing bitmap image.

[image]
For example:

```
let cutImageRef: CGImage = originalImgView.image.cgImage?.cropping(to: cropOverlay.frame)
let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
```

**Update:**

Also you should use scales because size of you imageView not the same as size of image

```
if let image = imageView.image {
  let wScale = (image.size.width / imageView.frame.width) * UIScreen.main.scale
  let hScale = (image.size.height / imageView.frame.height) * UIScreen.main.scale
  ...
  // Create cropping area using scales
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, it crops a small part of my UIImage, makes it big and starts from x,y = 0 again. I've even tried the code from Apple, it is wrong :(

Comment: Upvoted this, it’s definitely the correct way to do it. If you tried and it didn’t work, then post an update to your question showing the code you used and I’m sure someone can help further.

Comment: Sure, @PeteMorris, I'm gonna post an update right now, thanks.

Comment: For some reason, that code makes the cropped image 2 times bigger (at least that's how it looks like to me)

Comment: PS: i guess the issue is on the UIImage size, if such size is big like 1500x2000, the crop result is a small portion of such image :(

Comment: You should not forget about scales in the calculation of the cropping area, I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks @AntonRodzik, although I don't kow how to create cropping area.. I mean, now it's a custom ResizableImageView, custom class of UIImageView that handles touchesMoved and touchesBegan in order to be resized by dragging its corners

Comment: You just should create cgrect for cropping using scales

Comment: well, I don't know how to that, I was expecting a bit of code, but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale)
```

The first param's type is CGSize, not CGRect. you can try this:

```
CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [originalImageView.image CGImage];
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImageRef, rect);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
```

Comment: that's Objective-C, my question needs a Swift code answer :)

Comment: I could translate your Obj-.C code into Swift, like this:  let cutImageRef: CGImage = (imageToEdit.cgImage?.cropping(to: cropOverlay.frame))!
        let croppedImg = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef) but it doesn't work properly yet...